# Blog Post On Home Page Displaying Page Published Date Not Post Published Date

Tags: posts

I am displaying the latest post from my blog on a custom home page template but the date posted for the post is pulling through the date the homepage was published not the date the post was published. How can I fix this. Here is my code.

```
<?php 
        $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 1,
        'order' => 'DESC'
        );

        $rp = new WP_Query( $args );
        $post_date = get_the_time( 'd-m-y', $post->ID );

        if($rp->have_posts()) :
        while($rp->have_posts()) : $rp->the_post();
        echo '<p class="authDate">Surrey Creative | ';
        echo $post_date;
        echo '</p>';
        echo '<h3>';
        the_title();
        echo '</h3>';
        echo '<div class="snippet">';
        the_excerpt();
        echo '</div>';
        echo '<a href="'; 
        echo esc_url( get_the_permalink( $post_id ) );
        echo '" class="read-more button link">';
        echo 'Read More <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>';                

        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata(); 
        endif;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected,  this code gets the date of the current post:

```php
$post_date = get_the_time( 'd-m-y', $post->ID );
```

But you're not inside the post loop yet, so the current post is the page you're on. `the_post` is what sets the current post, so you need to call this inside the loop, not outside.

There are some other issues:

- Use an editor that auto-indents code, especially if you're sharing it, indentation avoids an entire group of bugs
- `echo esc_url( get_the_permalink( $post_id ) );` refers to `$post_id` which is never defined, it's just pulled out of thin air
- There is no `else` case, if no posts are found it'll just be blank

Comment: Thanks for the insight Tom. However the problem remains because I am just displaying the latest post on the home page, I am not doing so within the loop. is there a way of grabbing the post date to display here whilst remaining outside of the loop?

Comment: There's no reason to grab it outside the loop in the code you posted, in fact it is the cause of your problem. Notice I'm not talking about the main post loop, but your custom post loop with `$rp->`. `$rp->the_post` sets the current post, but you fetched the date ***before*** that, and that's the fundamental mistake. `get_the_time` uses the current post, and `$post` is the current post. Until you call `$rp->the_post()` the current post is the homepage. After you call `$rp->the_post()` the current post is changed. Keep in mind it's harder to see this because all the indentation is the same

Comment: Hero thanks tom, makes sense now and that's fixed it.